# How to get all ip address of nodes in bitcoin testnet

Tags: testnet

There are many service to get all fo the ip address in bitcoin mainnet but I can't find the similar way to get all ip address in testnet.Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Which service do you use for mainnet?

Comment: @Prayank You can use api.blockchair.com/bitcoin/nodes to get mainnet nodes

Answer (score 3):

Different ways to get IP address of bitcoin nodes on testnet:

1: Check `A` DNS record for one of the domains used by DNS seeds:

```
testnet-seed.bitcoin.jonasschnelli.ch
seed.tbtc.petertodd.org
seed.testnet.bitcoin.sprovoost.nl
testnet-seed.bluematt.me
```

[image: dns-records]

I tried connecting to one of these nodes on port 18333 with `addnode` to confirm and it works.

2. Run own test DNS seeder to crawl the network using https://github.com/sipa/bitcoin-seeder
3. Run your own bitcoin node, save IP address for peers, ban all for 1 hour, save IP address for new peers and repeat until you have enough addresses. You can get lot of addresses in few minutes: https://pastebin.com/raw/jxkEpgEq
4. Use Bitnodes API which returns testnet nodes as well in the response: https://bitnodes.io/api/#list-nodes or Use [shodan](https://www.shodan.io/search/report?query=User-Agent%3A%2FSatoshi%2F+port%3A%2218333%22) filters like `User-Agent:/Satoshi/ port:"18333"` which returns few nodes

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried to use a bitcoin full node to collect address and finally get a lot of address.But just a few of them can connect.i think the fourth way you said is a best way but i don't know which api can do it in testnet